# What's the best to make between WinPhone 8.1 and UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.winphone

I was asking myself about this question.

Finaly, if I want to make a WinPhone app (with Xamarin.Forms, next of Android/iOS plateform), what could be the best between UWP and WinPhone 8.1 project?

I don't think to make a Windows App at the moment, just something for phone, because my website is already available for computer so..

Moreover, WinPhone 8.1 works on Windows 10 mobile isn't? So if any updates are released, the code will still works no?

Thank :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***what could be the best between UWP and WinPhone 8.1 project?***

Since you only wants to make a windows phone app, so it is ok to use the Windows Phone 8.1 app or UWP app, but it will be better if you can choose to use the UWP app, because currently there are some new featers in the UWP app, [you can check here for the new features in the UWP app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/develop).
Besides, some known issues that happen in the Windows Phone 8.1 app have been fixed in the UWP app.

***Moreover, WinPhone 8.1 works on Windows 10 mobile isn't?***

Yes, you are right, currently the Windows Phone 8.1 app will work on the Windows 10 mobile.

***So if any updates are released, the code will still works no?***

I can not tell you the accurate answer, because we do not know what kinds of update will be released in the future. But currently, it should work.

Comment: Thank for your answer, really interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

In short, UWP apps will be the future and have some cool features (such as Continuum support) as @Fang Peng pointed out, however, there are other factors to consider.

For example (and chief among them,) Windows 10 Mobile so far, has only penetrated (or been installed on) about 11-12% of ALL windows phone/mobile devices. The significance of this is that by choosing UWP only, you're only serving about 11-12% of all windows phone/mobile users.

In my opinion, you should do both if you have the time and resources; much of the functional code for WP and UWP apps can be shared in a Portable Class Library (PCL) to cut down on the amount of code you have to write. 
If you can't launch both at the same time, maybe develop/release WP8.1 first and then the UWP app because you can later drop support for the WP8.1 app (right after the first release if you want) and focus on the UWP, but you've got all your bases covered.

Perhaps you should look into Xamarin. I'm using it now to create an app for UWP (Windows 10 PC & Mobile), Windows 8.1, Windows Phone 8.1, iOS and Android. It's really great, especially if you're app is pretty straight forward, but requires a lot of extending (due it's limitless flexibility) if you want it do complex UI or platform-specific stuff, which is kind of a trade off. If you can get past the fairly steep and lengthy learning curve, you can literally do anything you want to in a cross platform manner.